# Connection between Apache Kafka and JMS

Tags: jms, apache-kafka

I was wondering could Apache Kafka communicate and send messages to JMS? Can I establish connection between them? For example, I'm using JMS in my system and it should send messages to the other system that uses Kafka

Comment: do you mean without coding?

Comment: @ShawnGuo Yes, only sending requests etc.

Comment: @BohdanMyslyvchuk suppose it's not yet there - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answering bit late, but if I understood correctly the requirement.

If the requirement is synchronous messaging from 
client->JMS->Kafka --- > consumer
then following is not the solution, but if its ( and most likely) the async requirement like:

client->JMS | ----> Kafka ---> consumer

then, this would be related to KafkaConnect framework which is solving the problem of how to integrate different sources and sinks with Kafka.

http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/
http://www.confluent.io/product/connectors

so what you need is a JMSSourceConnector.

Comment: I dont see any documentation on JMSSourceConnector on Confluent page, is it by default available or we need to write custom class for this?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. And the two are incomparable concepts. JMS is a vendor-neutral API specification of a messaging service.

While Kafka may be classified as a messaging service, it is not compatible with the JMS API, and to the best of my knowledge there is no trivial way of adapting JMS to fit Kafka's use cases without making significant compromises.

However, if your needs are simply to move messages between Kafka and a JMS-compliant broker, then this can easily be achieved by either writing a simple relay app that consumes from one and publishes onto another, or use something like **Kafka Connect**, which has pre-canned sinks for most data sources, including JMS brokers, databases, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is the reverse of the previous answer:

Kafka Producer -> Kafka Broker -> JMS Broker -> JMS Consumer

then you would need a KafkaConnect Sink like the following one from Data Mountaineer

http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/jms.html

Comment: Confluent now provides a JMS client in the Confluent Enterprise 3.2 distribution.